# It isn’t that you must stop now

Tags: grammaire, anglais, négation

> Il faut que vous vous arrêtiez maintenant.

means “You must stop now.” , while

> Il ne faut pas que vous vous arrêtiez maintenant.

means “You must not stop now.”;  how can one say

> It isn’t that you must stop now.

?

Comment: @PapaPoule thx i've updated the question, sorry for typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plain way to say that is amost a literal translation, as follows;

- Ce n'est pas qu'il faille que vous vous arrêtiez maintenant.
- Ce n'est pas que vous deviez vous arrêter maintenant.

It can be said differently though, more explicitly;

- Que vous deviez vous arrêter maintenant n'est pas la question.

Comment: Thx , but is there a way to say using “il * faut*”? Or have to be “ce n’est pas que il faut”?

Comment: @athos It seems to me that you can't use the indicative mood here; only the subjunctive will do. ("il faut" is "indicatif présent", "il faille" is "subjonctif présent"). However it is possible that some people will use the indicative; personally I don't.

Comment: While grammatically acceptable, the 3rd one "*Que vous deviez vous arrêter maintenant n'est pas la question*" is not an idiomatic turn of phrase, and even if it is, "*pas la question*" differs in meaning and tone: more emphatic, forceful, leaving no doubt. Which is different from the hesitant "*It isn’t / It's not that ... (It's just that ...)*" in the OP's phrasing.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens "It isn't that you must stop now." is synonymous with "It isn't a matter of your having to stop now.". "Que vous deviez vous arrêter maintenant n'est pas la question" is perfectly correct grammatically and  idiomatic; I find nothing wrong with it; the style is just not popular.

Comment: If you insist, I'm not looking to convince you otherwise or anything. But the fact remains that no native French speakers speak like this. To put it bluntly, the sentence "*Que vous deviez vous arrêter maintenant n'est pas la question*" itself doesn't make sense from a French speaker's perspective, I'm afraid. And your interpretation of the English construction "*It isn't that you must stop now*" is not accurate, either... If you are not convinced, wait and see how other French speakers debunk your claims.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Let's take this sentence: "Que la terre tourne autour du soleil n'est pas la réponse à la question.". There is nothing wrong in this turn of phrase, neither grammatically nor on the count of idiomaticity and I've heard used in a multitude of instances all my life. It's the same form; do you reject this  example ?

Comment: "Que vous deviez vous arrêter maintenant n'est pas la question" me semble tout à fait correct et idiomatique. La longueur et relative complexité de la formulation font qu'elle ne sera sans doute pas utilisée dans un discours informel et/ou oral (comme "ce  n'est pas qu'il faille que vous vous arrêtiez"), mais affirmer "doesn't make sense from a French speaker's perspective" est faux. N'importe quel francophone devrait être à même de comprendre.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Here are cases of the fronting of the "subordonnée complétive sujet": (https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-42731.php) (examples in the exercises),  "Que Jean vienne demain ne fait aucun doute.", "Que les enfants soient rentrés pour minuit est indispensable. ".

Answer (score 5):

Vous pourriez utiliser

> Vous n'êtes pas obligé(s) de vous arrêter maintenant
>
> Vous n'avez pas à vous arrêter maintenant

Ou encore

> Vous ne devez pas vous arrêter maintenant

Attention cependant à l'ambiguïté de cette dernière formulation (cfr les commentaires ci-dessous) car "ne pas devoir s'arrêter" peut être compris soit comme une interdiction de s'arrêter (donc une obligation de continuer) soit comme une absence d'obligation (donc une possibilité de continuer ou d'arrêter selon son  bon vouloir), là où l'anglais dispose de "must" et "have to" pour nuancer l'obligation: "You must not stop" vs. "You don't have to stop".

On peut facilement lever cette ambiguïté via l'emploi d'un adverbe :

> Vous ne devez pas [nécessairement/obligatoirement/impérativement/...] vous arrêter maintenant

Finalement, pour un discours un peu plus formel employant un subjonctif

> Ce n'est pas qu'il vous faille arrêter maintenant

Mais dans ce cas il vous faut une suite car seule, cette phrase ne tient pas.

Comment: Il me semble que vos traductions ne correspondent pas ; une traduction "en retour" ("back translation") de la première des trois possibilités que vous mentionnez est  "You mustn't stop now."; je passerais à côté de quelque chose de capital?

Comment: Je traduirais la première par "You don't have to stop now". Selon moi toutes ont globalement le même sens, à savoir que arrêter n'est pas une obligation.

Comment: I must agree with @LPH on the first sentence you proposed. This is literally **You must not stop**. I agree with you on the others, though.

Comment: I can agree there's some ambiguity because of the "double negation" induced by "arrêter". But if you consider that "devoir" is a synonym for "être obligé de" , then "ne pas devoir" is a perfectly valid synonym for "ne pas être obligé de". I would translate "You must not stop" by "Vous ne pouvez pas vous arrêter" ou "Vous devez continuer" (with a verb change to convey the meaning of "ne pas s'arrêter", so "continuer"). I will update my answerto clarify this ambiguity though.

Comment: « Ce n'est pas que vous soyez obligés de vous arrêter » marche aussi.

Comment: +1 for your last point (Mais dans ce cas il vous faut une suite ...) which is key, imo, to fully capturing ["the hesitant {meaning/tone of} "It isn’t that ..." in the OP's phrasing"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36117/36118#comment71934_36118) aptly noted by @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens but imo, your 1st 3 options, ambiguous or not (as well as LPH's last option), are "[too] emphatic, forceful, [& sans] doubt." OP's phrase didn't continue w/a "but ...", but it's implied & imo, is captured fully & unambiguously w/Stéphane's "Ce n'est pas que vous soyez obligés de vous arrêter, mais..."